# Input stops list

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to python and encountered a problem, in this scenario, it doesn't fully print the list at once, instead it prints one line of the list everytime you fill something in at the input area. How do i fix this? If i remove the whole part after the input, it does print the full list at once.

```
balance = 2000000000
promotion = 1
gadget = 1
tech = 0

multi_1 = 1
multi_2 = 1
multi_3 = 1

x = 50**multi_1
z = 50**multi_2
y = 50**multi_3

promotion_price = 5000*x
gadget_price = 10000*z
tech_price = 200000*y

shop = [ "[1] Work promotion - Upgrade your work efficiency!" , promotion_price , "[2] Gadgets - Upgrade your stealing efficiency!" ,
         gadget_price , "[3] Reality:Technology - Unlock a new world!" , tech_price , "Type the number of the item/upgrade you want to purchase"]

for i in range(len(shop)):
            print(shop[i])
            shop_purchase = input("What would you like to purchase? ")
            if shop_purchase == "1" and balance>= promotion_price: 
                balance -= promotion_price
                promotion += 1
                multi_1 += 1
                print("Purchased! Your balance is now %s" % balance)
        
        elif shop_purchase == "2" and balance>gadget_price:
            balance -= gadget_price
            gadget += 1
            multi_2 += 1
            print("Purchased! Your balance is now %s" % balance)
            
        elif shop_purchase == "3" and balance>=tech_price:
            balance -= tech_price
            tech += 1
            print("Purchased! Your balance is now %s" % balance)
        
        else:
            print("You do not have enough money.")
```

Comment: Welcome! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your question lacks a consistently formatted [mcve], along with a precise description of its behaviour and the behaviour you would expect instead.

Comment: Are you trying to print list shop on each iteration?  `print(shop[i])` will only print the i-th element.  Perhaps you want `print(shop)`.  Also, not clear why you are looping over shop i.e. `for i in range(len(shop)):`.  You should loop `while True:` and then break when someone enters either a number or empty line to indicate they are done.

Comment: When you increment multi_1 (`multi_1 += 1`), did you also want to update x (`x = 50**multi_1`) and promotion_price (`promotion_price = 5000*x`)?  The same question for multi_2 and multi_3.